# Showing network interface for outbound traffic

Tags: networking, rhel, network-interface, scanner

I'm able to obtain outbound IP/port list using

```
netstat -atn | tr -s ' '| cut -f5 -d ' ' | grep -v '127.0.0.1'
```

My system has multiple IPs over two physical interfaces:

```
em1
em1:0
em1:1
em1:2
em2
```

Is there a way to specify which interface traffic (including "nested" configs such as "em:2") is going out over?

*Before downvoting, please provide me with an opportunity to help clarify my submission.*

Comment: Look at `ip route` and `ip addr` - this should be enough information to figure it out, usually one of your two IFs for local traffic, and the other one for everything else. If you have difficult routing tables for some reason, `ip route get a.b.c.d` will tell you the interface.

Comment: Could you clarify what you mean with `ip route get a.b.c.d`?  What input does `a.b.c.d.` represent?

Comment: Also will `ip route` show virtual interfaces like `em1:2` or is it only going to list the physical cards?  I'm only seeing `em1` and `em2` but I am unsure if it's taking into account the virtual interfaces.

Comment: a.b.c.d is the IP address for which you want to find the IF. Virtual interfaces are just the old kernel way of assigning multiple IPv4 addresses to an IF, that's why the newer `ip addr` doesn't show them.

Comment: Thanks, the `ip route get a.b.c.d` command shows the interface (along with interface IP address).  Helps debug a network issue I'm having.   If you'll add that as an answer I'll hook you up.